# What is the US constitutional basis for impeaching, trying and barring from future presidency a former US president?

Tags: us-constitution, impeachment

What is the US constitutional basis for the following actions?

1. Impeaching and trying a former US president?
2. Barring a former US president from elected a president in the future?

Comment: The "constitutional basis" is the Constitution.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: Would you care to elaborate, preferably into an answer?

Comment: First thing you should do before asking a question is search this site: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=impeachment . And use Google.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue the Constitutional basis of these actions would be the Constitution itself, namely Article II, Section 4:

> The President, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States, shall be removed from Office on Impeachment for, and Conviction of, Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors.

and Article I, Section 3, Clause 7:

> Judgment in Cases of Impeachment shall not extend further than to removal from Office, and disqualification to hold and enjoy any Office of honor, Trust or Profit under the United States: but the Party convicted shall nevertheless be liable and subject to Indictment, Trial, Judgment and Punishment, according to Law.

Note also, that as Hamilton explained in the Federalist Papers, the Impeachment process was a check brought over from England (it predated the formation of Britain by several centuries) as a check on Executive (read Monarchal) power of royal appointments, including Judges.

So, to answer your questions directly:

1. Serving out one's term or resigning is not a shield to impeachment, otherwise one could simply play "whack-a-mole", appointing the same individual repeatedly (which is also why future barring of the individual from governmental office is an option). The purpose of impeachment is, per Hamilton, to react to "political crimes"; "mundane" crimes are to be handle by the normal judicial system. Nixon did famously resign rather than be impeached, but he was barred from running again anyway, having served two terms as President. Congress at that time chose not to continue the impeachment process after his resignation (note that disqualification is an option, but not required, punishment that can be levied by Congress in the event of impeachment).
2. See Article I, Section 3, Clause 7, quoted above.

Comment: A minor point. Englsih practice never involved impeachment of a king, only of the King' s appointed officials. That did, of course, hamper the king's exercise of authority thought improper by Parliament.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Charles I may or may not agree with you :). But edits made to clarify.

Comment: Charles I was not impeached. He was indited for and convicted of treason, a quite different procedure (and legally very dubious under the then-existing English law, but that did not stop the execution).

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I was mostly being facetious with Charles I comment; although he was "removed from office" on the charges of "charges of high treason and 'other high crimes' ". (Charles I made similar legal arguments at his trial, hence 'may or may not agree').

Comment: Yes. I have in fact read the records of his trial, some years ago, and i understood the humor. But Parliament did not use the impeachment procedure. it debated how to proceed, a problem since treason was defined as an attack on the king. But in form the king was indicted for a crime, and executed after conviction. After the restoration, the trial was of course held to be invalid. Impeachment under the English system was a special procedure, closely imitated in the US constitution

Answer (score 0):

The issue is unclear.  Article II, Section 4 of the constitution authorizes the removal from office of "The President, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States" on "Impeachment for, and Conviction of, Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors."  Article I, Section 3 specifies that "Judgment in Cases of Impeachment shall not extend further than to removal from Office, and disqualification to hold and enjoy any Office of honor, Trust or Profit under the United States".

There is no specific provision allowing impeachment of, or an impeachment trial of a former holder of such an office.

The practice has been for the Senate to first vote on each article of Impeachment, and if and only if it voted to convict on any article, to then vote on whether to add disqualification from office to the judgement.

Several constitutional scholars have recently been quoted in the press to the4 effect that this means that a judgement of disqualification, when one is imposed,  is always imposed on a former office holder, as the conviction has already occurred at that point. Others have argued that the judgement is a single transaction, and it is not final until all the Senate votes are concluded, and so the person remains an office holder when the vote on disqualification is held. No court has ever addressed this issue.

There are two precedents for holding a Senate trial (or at least a Senate Vote) on a bill of impeachment after the office holder had, in one case, resigned, and in the other case, been removed from office by other means. In neither case did the Senate vote to convict. In neither case did the Senate explicitly reject the impeachment *because the person was no longer in office*, although in each case some senators favored that view. Neither case followed quite the same course of events as the recent impeachment of then-President Trump. Neither case was of a President: one was of a Senator, the other of a cabinet Secretary. Neither case was at all recent.

The House and Senate are, as another answer points out, constitutionally empowered to set their own procedures, although not to expand their constitutional powers. When the House voted to impeach Trump, he was the sitting President and they were clearly within their powers. The Senate is now debating what to do with the articles of impeachment passed by the House, including the issue of the constitutionality of holding a trial on them. There is no precedent for a US court overriding the Senate on any question of Impeachment. The constitution gives the Senate "sole power" to try all impeachments. If the Senate does not vote to convict, that should end the matter. If it votes to convict (which now seems unlikely) and then votes to disqualify Trump from future office, Trump could perhaps challenge that disqualification in court. That would require overruling or distinguishing *Nixon v US* (which was about a Judge Nixon, not President Nixon). How that might play out no one can reliably predict at this time. It is not a likely chain of events.

Comment: "... that a judgement of disqualification is always imposed on a former office holder..."  This is false and demonstrably so:  Judge Alcee Hastings was convicted on articles of impeachment by the U.S. Senate in 1988 (69-26 vote) and was immediately removed from office but no vote to disqualify him ever happened.   In 1992, Hastings won his Florida election for a Representative seat in the House and is to this day still a U.S. Representative.

Comment: @hszmv that misunderstands the meaning of the argument, which i thought was clear in my answer, but I have edited to further clarify. When and if a judgement of disqualification is imposed, the argument runs, it is on a then-former office holder.  Does that address your complaint?

Answer (score -4):

The Constitution allows both houses of Congress to set its rules and procedures.  They can "impeach" their house pets and farm animals if they want to spend their time on it.

The legal system is adversarial by design.  Which means the only way any government activity can be evaluated for being legal or illegal (i.e., "constitutional" or "unconstitutional") is when there is a party which has been legally harmed and which can bring a petition to challenge this action in court.

Until and unless there is a former President (or any public official) who

- loses an impeachment trial despite being tried after having left office,
- decides to challenge such an impeachment outcome in court,
- convinces the SCOTUS that there are grounds to reverse Nixon v US (whose outcome made all impeachments non-justiciable)

this question (of whether the Constitution supports such a trial) remains open.  Anyone who claims otherwise expresses an opinion.  Many of the people who do express such opinions are very well informed, but even well-informed and well-reasoned opinions do turn out to be wrong from time to time.

Comment: "The Constitution allows both houses of Congress to set its rules and procedures. They can 'impeach' their house pets and farm animals if they want to spend their time on it." 1. What does not count as their "house pets and farm animals"? If they impeach the whole of Supreme Court Justice, then the justices appeal to the Supreme Court and subsequently convinces the SCOTUS the congressional act as unconstitutional, what is to be done? Are we in a logical contradiction? 2. Does the meaning of "impeachment" up to arbitrary congressional interpretation?

Comment: I suppose your answer to my question 2 is affirmative given your first sentence. Do you agree?

Comment: @Hans as long as no party can claim harm from their actions in court, Congress can give it whatever meaning it chooses to give it.  Legal boundaries only exist when they can be legally enforced.

Comment: It’s worth nothing that only the House may impeach. The Senate’s trial is not called impeachment, nor may the Senate file articles of impeachment on its own.

Comment: @A.fm.  which part of the answer do you believe creates a different impression?  I used the word "impeachment" for the entire process, as is commonly accepted.  But I tried to call the Senate trial part of the process an "impeach trial" or just "trial".

Comment: The first two sentences taken together say that. The first sentence alone doesn’t. But there’s no indication your second sentence isn’t also referring to “both houses.”

Comment: @A.fm Yes, that was a possible way to read it.  I just edited to add clarity. Thanks.

Comment: -1 Art II Sec 4 permits impeachment and trial of "The President, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States". This does not include house pets. It is true that there is no explicit mechanism for enforcing this limit, nor is it clear if it includes former holders of such offices.

Comment: @DavidSiegel as you know, it doesn't explicitly include former office holders.  You are downvoting to express your political view.  I tried to provide an answer which would be as informative as possible to someone who is not asking a question to express their political position, but because they don't understand what is going on.  And you are trying to make this personal.  Please, stop.

Comment: @grovkin  My objection is solely to the "house pets" line which seems to imply that there is no Constitutional limit on who can be impeached. As for my personal views, while I dislike Trump, I was opposed to the 2nd impeachment, not that I was consulted. Remove the "house pets" or make it clear such an act would be a violation of the constitution, although there is no explicit mechanism to enforce that limit, and i will upvote.

Comment: @DavidSiegel they can, in fact, impeach house pets.  It's not constitutional, but neither are some of the laws they pass.  When they pass those laws, however, they can be challenged in court.  So there is a mechanism to enforce constitutionality of laws.  No such mechanism, for enforcing constitutionality of impeachments, exists though.  As long as impeachments remain non-justiciable, their constitutionality will rely exclusively on voluntary compliance by the Congress.

Comment: @grovkin Then say that in the answer, please.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, yeah, i think I am going to revert to the version of the answer that was best received.

Comment: @grovkin I missed Revision 3. I would have upvoted that.

Comment: @DavidSiegel having reconsidered it, I am going to stand by the short version. I didn't say it was constitutional for the senators to do this, so I don't need to say that it isn't.  In fact, as I already said, the Senate *can* and does take unconstitutional actions. But in some instances there are checks to prevent them (such as SCOTUS declaring legislature unconstitutional). Nothing prevents this type of unconstitutional action because of a lack of a mechanism to check it. I think the shorter version of the answer addresses the gist of the question which makes it a better communication style.

Comment: @grovkin The first two sentences of your answer ("The constitution allows ... They can ...") seem to me to petty clearly imply that such an act would be constitutional. That is why i retain the downvote. Obviously you disagree. I would add that jsut such a possibility is cited by the concurrence  in *Nixon v US* as a reason not to foreclose SCOTUS intervention in a future impeachment case (the cited example was deciding the outcome by a coin toss). So if it happened the Court might act.

Comment: @DavidSiegel maybe if you didn't read the rest of the sentence you could get such an impression.  But the full sentence was that the Constitution allows both hoses to set their procedure.  That's not an implication that the constitution allows them to do other things.  It's also obviously a true sentence.  I am aware of the concurrence in Nixon v US.  And because of time spent on SE, I am also aware of what it means.  It is effectively an expression of hope that a court would act in such a case.  And I share the sentiment.  But it doesn't create an automatic exception to the current procedure.

Comment: @grovkin I fear we shall have to agree to disagree. I honestly think the 2 sentences read in full, suggest that a "house pet" impeachment would be constitutional albeit absurd. I understand that your intended meaning  was that such an act would be unconstitutional, but there is no mechanism for addressing such an act, besides  Congress own good sense, which is not always so good. I don't disagree with your intended meaning, just with your form of expression.